# Are (/\s{2,}/) and (/\s{2,''}/) the same? If not then please explain the difference

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I just wanted to know difference between  `(/\s{2,}/)` and `(/\s{2,''}/)` regular expressions?

Please explain with an example.

Comment: None of them is a valid regular expression. So they are "the same" *invalid* JS literals.

Comment: @zerkms `(/\s{2,})` is a valid regex, granted it _is_ missing the delimiters... as for `''` in the quantifier, yea that looks bogus.

Comment: @zamnuts: until it's completely fixed - I'm not sure it makes sense to guess. Who knows what else OP has omitted.

Comment: (/\s{2,}/) and (/\s{2,''}/).sorry I forgotten to add forward slash at the end of the expression.

Comment: @amit325: so fix the original question

Comment: @amit325 try it in [Online Regex Tester](http://regex101.com/)

Comment: Did you mean the `\s{2,}` regex? @amit325

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Are `\s{2,}` and `\s{2,''}` the same?

NO, both are different.

- `\s{2,}`  --> Two or more spaces.
- `\s{2,''}` --> Matches a white space character[`\r\n\t\f`] and literal `{2,''}`

Comment: This is correct, I'd just like to clarify - the second one is matching _one_ whitespace character _and_ the whole of `{2,''}` if present. [This is how it looks](http://regex101.com/r/aA0wG8/1)